# How to find rows with non utf8 characters in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, utf-8, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my snowflake db, a table has non-utf8 characters.
How can I create a view on top of it which will only have utf8 characters; either by excluding the rows with non-utf8 characters or by replacing them?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post some sample data/code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible to check for non-utf with a test like this:

```
MY_STRING IS NOT NULL AND TRY_HEX_DECODE_STRING(HEX_ENCODE(MY_STRING)) IS NULL
```

But then I don't have data to test with.
To reencode the string to utf-8, you can use a JavaScript function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TO_UTF8(BINARY_TEXT BINARY)
RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT STRICT IMMUTABLE AS '
  var win1252 = [ /* C1 controls */
    8364,  129, 8218,  402, 8222, 8230, 8224, 8225,
     710, 8240,  352, 8249,  338,  141,  381,  143,
     144, 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8211, 8212,
     732, 8482,  353, 8250,  339,  157,  382,  376
  ];
  return String.fromCharCode(
    ...Array.from(BINARY_TEXT).map(x => (x < 128 || x > 159) ? x : (win1252[x - 128]))
  ); /* .map(...) can be removed if no conversion from win1252 needed */
';

SELECT NVL(TRY_HEX_DECODE_STRING(HEX_ENCODE(MY_STRING)),
           TO_UTF8(HEX_ENCODE(MY_STRING)::BINARY));
```

Comment: This works! It detects rows with non-utf8 characters. Now, is there a way to replace those characters (so not to discard the row)?

Comment: I've expanded my answer with an expression that replaces illegal bytes with space.  Should be used when the test above fails.

Comment: Thanks but 
`select * 
from table 
where TRY_HEX_DECODE_STRING(HEX_ENCODE(field)) is null` 
returns 3 rows while 
`select *
from table 
where 
field <>
TRY_HEX_DECODE_STRING(
    REPLACE(
      REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(HEX_ENCODE(field), '(..)', '\\1,'),
        '([89A-F].,)',
        '20,'),
      ',',
      ''
    )
  )` 
returns  484 rows. What are your thoughts?

Comment: The expression above was only meant to be used for invalid utf-8.  Instead, I made a JavaScript function to reencode a string, and even convert from win1252 to utf-8 if that is the real format of the string.  Please see the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Though I tried Hans's solution, it isn't working in all scenarios. Hence, I wrote a very simple Snowflake Javascript stored procedure that will replace all characters that are not part of keyboard.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.REPLACE_NON_UTF8_CHARS(STR varchar)
RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT STRICT IMMUTABLE AS '  
  return STR.replace(/[^ -~]+/g, '''')    
';
```

This can be implemented in the sql like below.

```
SELECT MYSCHEMA.REPLACE_NON_UTF8_CHARS(MY_STRING) AS MY_STRING
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'ABC,D�E123 5' AS MY_STRING
)
```

And the output will be like below. You can see the junk character after `D` is replaced by empty character.

`ABC,DE123 5`